# Nasa paralell benchmarks - MPI error

Tags: c, bash, parallel-processing, mpi, benchmarking

I have a pretty special problem. I need to review NASA Parallel Benchmarks for my school project, but I found it to be a very problematic task :-) At first, I tried to work with IS (integer sort), but the code wasn't able to compile, and I found out, that I need to rewrite *make.def* file. So I rewrote it's variable for *mpi.h* and compiled it, but the program keeps alerting me:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_rank(108): MPI_Comm_rank(comm=0x0, rank=0x6084e8) failed
PMPI_Comm_rank(66).: Invalid communicator
```

To be honest, I don't really know, should I do know. I tried even changing the old compilers, like *cc* to *gcc* etc. but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Last thing which I tried to rewrite was the variable CMPI_LIB, but I have no idea how to do it correctly.

Thank you very much for all your responses ;-) 
And I'm sorry for my bad English, I'm not a native speaker.

---

The whole benchmark is here for download (cca 600kB): uloz.to/xTSEzTX8/npb3-3-1-zip

File *is.c* which I'm trying to compile and launch: hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2436

Makefile: hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2437

File *make.common* - takes care of compiling files with special functions etc.: hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/2438

My *make.def* is here: [#veeylg84-46196 - BASH - Sourcecode](http://www.sourcepod.com/veeylg84-46196)

Structure of files in my 'benchmark folder': http://www.sourcepod.com/sozaoh48-46200

Comment: Which program causes the error? How the source code looks like? How did the compilation command for it looked like? Which MPI implementation do you have? Your question is probably unanswerable as itstands.

Comment: My mistake, now I tried to improve it a little, I've added a link to download the whole benchmark (it's a pretty small package). I think, that the only thing that needs to be changed is the variable to "MPI linker" CMPI_LIB, but I don't know, which program should I assign to it.

The error is caused by the programm created by compiling is.c and for compilation I use embedded Makefiles - should I post all the codes here, so you don't have to download the archive? If it's better, don't hesitate to tell me :-)

My 'mpicc' version is *cc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2*

Comment: I am not going to download some software and debug it for you (you should say at least which benchmark fails), but maybe someone will do it. I think it is pretty unlikely you should change the linker, because you have a run-time failure. MPI programs are normally link with `mpicc`, `mpif90` and similar.

Comment: IS benchmark fails, I wrote it in the description of my problem - if you mean something more specific, I'm sorry, to be honest I have never worked with some old code like this (some parts are from 80's I think) or with MPI, so I'm really confused.

Ok, I'll try to look somewhere else for this insidious mistake :-)

Comment: Ok, can't you paste the source code which cases the error into your question? Do you have a backtrace with line numbers?

Comment: I've added *is.c*, Makefile and make.common, so you should be able to see everything important afaik... Unfortunately I have no backtrace, only alert I've got is in the description :/

Comment: Why don't you paste the relevant source in the question? And why do you bother with make and Makefiles when testing a single source file? Did you try to do some debugging? SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: I have added the relevant source - it's the file *is.c*. I must bother with make, because this benchmark want to compile with several other files, with functions for printing results etc. And I didn't try any debug like step-by-step, because I have no idea, how to do it with MPI and Eclipse has problems importing this...

Comment: So you are just basically waiting someone to do it for you, good to know.

Comment: I'd love to have somebody, who'd tell me how, I've tried to get it working for several days. So far I've found nothing useful and nobody, who'd know what's wrong with the code. But I won't bother you anymore, I'll try to ask somewhere else. 

Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

The `PMPI_Comm_rank(108): MPI_Comm_rank(comm=0x0, rank=0x6084e8) failed` message tells a lot. Your `MPI_COMM_WORLD` constant is `0` which is not the case with MPICH-based (as one could guess from the format of the error message) implementations. It is a compile-time constant in MPICH (`#define MPI_COMM_WORLD ((MPI_Comm)0x44000000)`) and a run-time constant reference in Open MPI. The #1 reason for such errors is mixing MPI implementations, i.e. including `mpi.h` from one implementation and linking against the libraries of another one.

As evident from your `make.def`, you are including `mpi.h` from a dummy MPI implementation and linking against a real MPI library. This simply won't work. Since `mpicc` takes care of passing the right include paths and library options to the backend compiler, you don't have to set `CMPI_LIB` or `CMPI_INC` explicitly and should leave them *empty* instead. Those are reserved for the case when the MPI implementation does not provide compiler wrappers (`mpicc`, `mpif90`, etc.) and one has to explicitly specify all options, which is the case with e.g. MS-MPI.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I'm afraid, that my problem is bigger than this :-(

I've "outcommented" the content of those two variables, but the error is still here.

Here is my _make.def_ now:
http://pastebin.com/G5qq4DkX

P.s.: I'm trying to run my code with command _mpirun -n 4 ./is.A.4_ - maybe that's the problem? I'm really out of ideas, I feel like I've tried everything possible :-)